# How do I recycle old MacBook Pro batteries?

Tags: battery

Can I return an old 15-inch MBP rechargeable battery to Apple, or does it have to be disposed of locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disposal and/or recycling of batteries will differ depending on your local jurisdiction, namely because of local laws.

In some jurisdictions you can take your old electronic equipment, including batteries, to any Apple Retail Store. The local store will ensure that it will be recycled in a responsible manner.

Based on your profile, I see you're based in Germany. Germany is one of those places where Apple will happily take your batteries.

For more info, see [So einfach wie Apple Produkte sollte auch ihr Recycling sein](https://www.apple.com/de/recycling/)<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> The UK english version of the above referenced page is: [Recycling an Apple product is as easy as it is good for the planet](https://www.apple.com/uk/recycling/).

Comment: Actually, I need to update my profile. I'm not in Deutschland anymore.

Comment: Ah, okay! :) Well, in case you still need to double-check, you can change the URL to replace the `de` in https://www.apple.com/de/recycling/ with whatever the country code is that Apple uses for your location. For example, for the UK site `de` is replaced with `uk`, for the Australian site it's replaced with `au` and so on. The only exception to this is the native US which has no code at all. If you're not sure what code to use, go to this [page](https://www.apple.com/choose-your-country/) and hover over the flag icon for your location.